# Need jQuery drop down menu to close only when someone clicks outside of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, click

I currently have a jQuery drop down menu, where one clicks a button, then a search box appears below. So when the menu drops down after someone clicks the button, the search box needs to stay open/active until someone clicks *outside* of the search box.

Currently this script works well, except for the fact that when one clicks inside the search box, it closes. I need to have it to where the menu closes only when one clicks *outside* of the search box, and not in it. Any help would be much appreciated!

//HTML

```
<div class="click-nav">
  <ul class="searchbox">
    <li> <a class="tnsearch">Search Button</a>
      <ul id="searchboxul">
        <li>
          <div id="search-box">
            <!--Search box here-->
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

//Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.click-nav > ul').toggleClass('searchbox js');
    $('.click-nav .js ul').hide();

    $('.click-nav .js').click(function(e) {
        $('.click-nav .js ul').slideToggle(200);
        $('.tnsearch').toggleClass('active');
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $(document).click(function() {
        if ($('.click-nav .js ul').is(':visible')) {
        $('.click-nav .js ul', this).slideUp();
        $('.tnsearch').removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle to reproduce your issue? Here is your code : http://jsfiddle.net/VWZyv/

Comment: Sure thing, I updated it. Thanks! http://jsfiddle.net/VWZyv/7/

Comment: u mean whenever i click It should be stay open opened  , once Nav menu is clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to USE $('.click-nav .js .tnsearch').click(function(e) { as this points to specific element. Please see code below and fiddle.

Working fiddle  [***FIDDLE***](http://jsfiddle.net/VWZyv/17/)

```
$(function() {
$('.click-nav > ul').toggleClass('searchbox js');
$('.click-nav .js ul').hide();
$('.click-nav .js .tnsearch').click(function(e) {
$('.click-nav #searchboxul').slideToggle(200);
$('.tnsearch').toggleClass('active');
e.stopPropagation();
});

});
$(document).click(function(e){
    var targerEl=$(e.target);
    if(targerEl.is("html"))
    {
       $('.click-nav #searchboxul').slideUp(200);
    }
});
```